# Can I add a mapfragment into a listView

Tags: android, android-listview, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I want to create a list of cards each having a map fragment is that's possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I add a mapfragment into a listView

No, because fragments cannot go into any `AdapterView`.

Also, you cannot readily put scrollable things into other scrollable things. Both a map and a `ListView` know how to scroll vertically. You are welcome to experiment with putting `MapViews` into `ListView` rows, but I expect the results to be unusable.

Comment: Are you sure? @CommonsWare I just managed to implement YouTubePlayerFragments into CardViews in a ReyclerView.

Comment: @Flyview: First, `RecyclerView` is not an `AdapterView`. Second, my statement is based on [Dianne Hackborn's statements about this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/ZmkLo7lxm9k), and since she created the fragments implementation in the first place, her opinion would seem to carry some weight.

Comment: Ha-ha OK yes my mistake! @CommonsWare